# Does Liveness probe verify certificate if scheme is set to HTTPS in kubernetes?

Tags: https, kubernetes, probe

Does liveness probe in kubernetes verify Certificate for https request? I am using a self-signed certificate for my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as per the official documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

> If scheme field is set to HTTPS, the kubelet sends an HTTPS request skipping the certificate verification.